# Google cloud function max timeout 540 seconds not working for client

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, timeout

I have a google cloud function that taking execution time like 2 mins and i changed the max timeout to 540 seconds in cloud functions console. Then function executed in 2 mins with 200 status code.
[image: This is the function logs]

But from client side after 60 secs, I'm getting error saying "Error 502 (Server Error)!!1 The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds"[image: Error coming in client side]

Comment: What are the Cloud Functions logs? Do you have details to share? Can you also share the HTTP request difference between your test and the client side test?

Comment: When I call HTTP request from postman it is taking 60305 ms with 502 Bad Gateway status code. If you see in function logs it took 120287 ms and completed with 200 status code. I'm not able to get the response if the function executes more than one minute. @guillaumeblaquiere

Answer (score 1):

It's a postman issue. Go to file, settings and set the request timeout to 0

[image]

Comment: And if you set it to 600?