# Google Cloud Functions timeout limit changes

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I have a Google Cloud function that was working for the last weeks. I removed it and try to deploy, getting this error:

> INVALID_ARGUMENT: The timeout for functions with an event trigger cannot exceed 540 seconds.

This was the command used to deploy and update (**and it was working until today**):

```bash
gcloud functions deploy import-XXXXXXX-function \
--gen2 \
--runtime=go119 \
--memory=128Mi \
--timeout=t30m \
--region=$REGION \
--source="$ROOT" \
--entry-point=ImportXXXXXXX \
--trigger-event-filters="type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized" \
--trigger-event-filters="bucket=$BUCKET" \
--set-env-vars=STAGE=$STAGE
```

I can see that the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/timeout) was updated days ago (Last updated 2023-02-02 UTC.) and now the max timeout for event-driven functions is 540 seconds.

So two question:

1. My job is going to process a files that sometimes is taking around 15 minutes. What to do now?
2. How to verify that the timeout limit was the latest change in the doc?

Answer (score 1):

Agreed this is wrong and has changed recently.
The [gcloud cli documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--timeout) suggests `--gen2` is higher and 540s is the limit for `--gen1`:

[image: Shows limits for gen1 and gen2]

I also had an environment was a `--timeout=3600` which was working until quite recently. Something has changed :-/

Answer (score 0):

The timeout has always been 540 seconds. See (and note the dates):

- [Google cloud function max timeout 540 seconds not working for client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62742049/google-cloud-function-max-timeout-540-seconds-not-working-for-client)
- [Run FIrebase Cloud Function for more than 9 mins (540 sec)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68732826/run-firebase-cloud-function-for-more-than-9-mins-540-sec)

If you need more time for a background/async execution, you can either break up your function into different parts, or you can use a different product, such as Cloud Run.  There is a [full example](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/run/create-trigger-storage-console) of how to do that.

You could also arrange to use App Engine or Compute Engine to stand up a server.

Comment: Hi Doug. It was working for the last month with 30 minutes as timeout. The script has been not touched from the first time released and on 2023-2-1 it deployed a new version with no problems. It started failing today. If it was the limit, in practice, it was not limiting anything.

Comment: Could be that the timeout was updated manual in the CloudRun after create it via Cloud Function? And then, It was working with gcloud because it updated it instead creating a new one?

Comment: I can't tell you why it worked before, but I can tell you that I've been working with Cloud Functions since before it was first released, and the timeout has always been documented at 540. Even if it did work in the past, I would not **expect** it to work differently than stated.

Comment: Confirmed. Working again with t30m. Cloud Function creates the Cloud Run image under the cover. You can change the timeout there (I updated to 3600 seconds). After that, I was able to deploy the function with t30m as timeout and it updated the Cloud Run image as well.

Comment: Maybe the real limitation is on the eventarc side used under the cover? So even with that timeout, for more that 9 minutes job, the message is not going to be marked as processed? Could be?

Comment: If so, you could end up with retry behavior that's unexpected.